# How to return all the message between two Users - Django/Python/Chat Building

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, chat

I'm building a simple chat with Django-Rest-Framework in Python.
I created a GET/POST methods for Users and Chat.

**MODEL**

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.base import Model

class User(models.Model):

    class Meta:

        db_table = 'user'

    user_firstname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user_lastname = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Chat(models.Model):

    class Meta:

        db_table = 'chat'
    
    from_message = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+')
    message = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    to_message = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+')
```

**SERIALIZERS**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import User, Chat

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:

        model = User
        fields = '__all__'

class ChatSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:

        model = Chat
        fields = '__all__'
```

**URLS**

```
from django.urls.conf import re_path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^users/$', views.UserList.as_view(), name='users-list'),
    re_path(r'^chat/$', views.ChatList.as_view(), name='chat-get-list'),
    re_path(r'^chat/(?P<from_id>.+)&(?P<to_id>.+)/$', views.ChatList.as_view(), name='chat-list'),
]
```

**VIEWS**

```
from rest_framework import generics, serializers
from .models import User, Chat
from .serializers import ChatSerializer, UserSerializer

class UserList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):

        queryset = User.objects.all()
        return queryset

class ChatList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Chat.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ChatSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Chat.objects.all()
        from_id = self.request.query_params.get('from_id')
        to_id = self.request.query_params.get('to_id')

        if from_id is not None and to_id is not None:
            queryset = Chat.objects.filter(from_message=from_id,to_message=to_id)
 #Probably my error is here, because I'm specifying the messages. I need to add something like 'to_message=to_id or from_id
        
        return queryset
```

**THE PROBLEM:**
When I send a message, I informed a from_id, to_id and a message itself, for example:

```
{
    "from_id":1,
    "message":"I'm sending a message to you",
    "to_id":2
},
{
    "from_id":2,
    "message":"I'm replying your message",
    "to_id":1
}
```

But when I'm trying to get all the messages between two persons, I get just what was send from_id to to_id, but I also need to return what was replyed, in that example the message "I'm replying your message".

I know that my problem is probably in the filter, but I don't know how to build in another way.

In that case, **how to return all the messages between two Users**?

Comment: Why not try [django channels](https://github.com/django/channels), It will make things easier.

Comment: I'm trying to learn pure Django to develop rest services! that was an exercise... but very good to know about that option. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve that problem just add at **views**:

```
queryset1 = Chat.objects.filter(from_id=from_id,to_id=to_id)
queryset2 = Chat.objects.filter(from_id=to_id,to_id=from_id)
queryset =  queryset1.union(queryset2)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).